# How to multiply longs within a drool

Tags: java, drools

I would like to write one line of code to calculate the number of milliseconds in 30 days.

```
long gracePeriod = 30/*days*/ * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

However, in the drool that will not work because it is assigning an int to a long.  So I figured I could do something like this.

```
long gracePeriod = 30l/*days*/ * 24l * 60l * 60l * 1000l;
```

But, that also will not work so I had to do something dumb like:

```
long grace1 = 30;
long grace2 = 24;
long grace3 = 60;
long grace4 = 1000;
long grace = grace1 * grace2 * grace3 * grace3 * grace4;
```

Is there any way to make this simpler.

Comment: Please put a language tag (java?), otherwise you are not likely to get views with just `drools`.

Comment: I had no problem with adding an `l` after each number - compiles fine.  What problem are you running into when attempting this method?

Comment: @NickRippe I get an ';' missing error when it runs.

Comment: Please file a jira for this. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES

Answer (score 0):

For me, all 4 of these samples work (and are cleaner than what you had to resort to).  If one or many isn't working for you, it's probably either a problem with your IDE or Java environment.  If so, let us know what java version you're running and the environment.

```
public class TempProject
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long gracePeriod = 30l /*days*/ * 24l * 60l * 60l * 1000l;
        long gracePeriod2 = 30l /*days*/ * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        long gracePeriod3 = ((long)30) /*days*/ * 24  * 60  * 60  * 1000;
        long gracePeriod4 = ((long) 30)/*days*/ * ((long) 24) * ((long) 60) * ((long) 60) * ((long) 1000);

        System.out.println(gracePeriod);
        System.out.println(gracePeriod2);
        System.out.println(gracePeriod3);
        System.out.println(gracePeriod4);
    }

}
```

Of course the easiest way is to hardcode the number ;)

```
long gracePeriod = 2592000000l;
```

Comment: I think the OP's problem is that this does not work in drools, not that it doesn't work in Java... so as far as I can see, this answer is irrelevant..

Comment: @Nim Isn't Drools hosted on JBoss which is a Java webserver?  I guess I was coming at this from the perspective of giving workarounds in Java, since the OP posted a Java sample.  If it is Drools specific, a Drools sscce would provide a way look further into the problem.

Comment: no it's not "hosted", the sytax is java like with a few additions - so it may be that not all java syntax is supported (be highly surprising if such a simple thing is not supported..)